# How can I update a OnetoOne related models instance in restframework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two related model a **user model** and **profile model**.

here's how the data looks like

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "phone_number": 9843945748,
    "email": "someEmial@gmail.com",
    "profile": {
        "first_name": "Updated",
        "last_name": "Updated",
        "avatar": null,
        "date_of_birth": "1995-22-01"
    }
}
```

How do I override update() method in serializer to just updated the profile fields. bypassing the USER MODEL required field which is *email, phone_number*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think If the id is of user than you can simple do in this way

```
def update(self,request):
    try:
       profile=Profile.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)
    except Profile.DoesnotExist:
        raise ValidationError("No user found for following id")
    profile.first_name= "Your name"
    profile.last_name ="Your last name"
    profile.save()
```

This might not be exact function but the main core logic can be this

Comment: You can accept answer If it helped you future users will also be benefitted

Comment: site. also @lord when I try to ran testCase on update url it greets me with the following error: **django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: account_profile.user_id** have you got any idea how to solve it?

Comment: You are trying to encorporate  one to one field with mutiple matches which is not possible while you are trying to save using save method use try execpt  with IntegrityError as Validation and raise your message like cannot add new user or something like that if you are not clear this way try asking new question and mention me